# Keep view the same on different computer

Tags: html, css, browser, viewport

Is it possible to keep the same view on all computers? Even if they are difference in size? Is it possible without using media queries?

So, on the computer where I originally created this 'site', it looked like this (simulated version):
[image: http://i58.tinypic.com/mq1wh.png]

This how I made it to look, and I want it to look the same on other computers.

On other computers it's different, the viewspace/size varies from computer to. (how it's seen on this computer without simulation as before):
[image: http://i58.tinypic.com/hta7ol.png]

HTML:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
      <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Styling%20-%20Nav%20Bar/navBar.css">
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Styling_Home_Page/preview_section.css">
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Styling_Home_Page/sections_home.css">
      <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:400,100,200,300,500,600,700,800,900' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
      <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=PT+Sans:400,700,400italic,700italic' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
      <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,100,300,100italic,300italic,400italic,500italic,500,700,700italic,900,900italic' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
      <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Condensed:300italic,400italic,700italic,400,700,300' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
      
      <script src="jQuery-Versions/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
      <script src="Scripts-DropdownMenu/dropdownMenuEffect.js"></script>
      <script src="Scripts-onClick/onclick.js"></script>
      
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="jQuery-slider1/css/responsive.css">
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="jQuery-slider1/css/sangarSlider.css">
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="jQuery-slider1/themes/default/default.css">
      
      <script type="text/javascript" src="jQuery-slider1/js/jquery.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="jQuery-slider1/js/jquery.velocity.min.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="jQuery-slider1/js/jquery.touchSwipe.min.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="jQuery-slider1/js/imagesloaded.min.js"></script>
      
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jQuery-slider1/js/sangarSlider/sangarBaseClass.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="jQuery-slider1/js/sangarSlider/sangarSetupLayout.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="jQuery-slider1/js/sangarSlider/sangarSizeAndScale.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="jQuery-slider1/js/sangarSlider/sangarShift.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="jQuery-slider1/js/sangarSlider/sangarSetupBulletNav.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="jQuery-slider1/js/sangarSlider/sangarSetupNavigation.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="jQuery-slider1/js/sangarSlider/sangarSetupSwipeTouch.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="jQuery-slider1/js/sangarSlider/sangarSetupTimer.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="jQuery-slider1/js/sangarSlider/sangarBeforeAfter.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="jQuery-slider1/js/sangarSlider/sangarLock.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="jQuery-slider1/js/sangarSlider/sangarResponsiveClass.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="jQuery-slider1/js/sangarSlider/sangarResetSlider.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="jQuery-slider1/js/sangarSlider/sangarTextbox.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="jQuery-slider1/js/sangarSlider/sangarVideo.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="jQuery-slider1/js/sangarSlider.js"></script>
    <script type='text/javascript'>
   jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('.mySlider').sangarSlider({
     timer : true, // true or false to have the timer
     width : 850, // slideshow width
           height : 500, // slideshow height
           fullWidth : true, // slider will scale to the container size
           fullHeight : false, // slideshow height will resize to browser height
           minHeight : 400, // slideshow min height
           maxHeight : 500, // slideshow max height, set to '0' (zero) to make it unlimited   
           continousSliding : false, // only works for horizontal-slide and vertical-slide      
           jsOnly : false,           
           directionalNav : 'autohide',
           themeClass : 'default'
    });
   })
  </script>
  </head>
  <body>
<script>
<?php
//function to retrieve posts from facebook’s server
function loadFB($fbID){
    $url = "http://graph.facebook.com/".$fbID."/feed?limit=3";
    // Update by MC Vooges 11jun 2014: Access token is now required:
    $url.= '&access_token=YOUR_TOKEN|YOUR_ACCESS_SECRET';// *

    //load and setup CURL
     $c = curl_init($url);
     curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    //get data from facebook and decode JSON
     $page = json_decode(curl_exec($c));
    //close the connection
     curl_close($c);
    //return the data as an object
     return $page->data;
}

/* Change These Values */
// Your Facebook ID
 $fbid = "190506416472588";
// How many posts to show?
 $fbLimit = 10;
// Your Timezone
date_default_timezone_set("America/Chicago");


/* Dont Change */
// Variable used to count how many we’ve loaded
 $fbCount = 0;
// Call the function and get the posts from facebook
 $myPosts = loadFB($fbid);


//loop through all the posts we got from facebook
foreach($myPosts as $dPost){
    //only show posts that are posted by the page admin
    if($dPost->from->id==$fbid){
        //get the post date / time and convert to unix time
         $dTime = strtotime($dPost->created_time);
        //format the date / time into something human readable
        //if you want it formatted differently look up the php date function
         $myTime=date("M d Y h:ia",$dTime);
        ?>
        <ul>
            <li><?php echo($dPost->message) . $myTime; ?></li>
        </ul>
        <?php
        //increment counter
         $fbCount++;
        //if we’ve outputted the number set above in fblimit we’re done
         if($fbCount >= $fbLimit) break;
    }
}
?>
</script>
    <div id="navBar">
        <div id="logo">
          
        </div>
        <div id="menu">
            <div id="menuTitle_Container">
                <a class="menuTitle" href="index.html">HOME</a>
                <a class="menuTitle" href="sneakers.html">SNEAKERS</a>
                <a class="menuTitle" href="clothing.html">ACESSORIES</a>
                <a class="menuTitle" href="acessories.html">SUPPORT</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
        <div id="dropdownMenu">
            <div id="dropdownMenu_SubmenuContainer">
                <div class="submenu_Container">
                    <div class="submenu_menuContainer">
                        <p class="clotheCategory">SNEAKERS</p>
                            <a class="submenuTitle" href="#">TRAINING</a>
                            <a class="submenuTitle" href="#">SPORTSWEAR</a>
                            <a class="submenuTitle" href="#">JORDANS</a>
                            <a class="submenuTitle" href="#">RUNNING</a>
                            <a class="submenuTitle" href="#">OTHERS</a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="submenu_menuContainer">
                        <p class="clotheCategory">HOT RIGHT NOW</p>
                            <a class="submenuTitle" href="#">ADIDAS YEEZY BOOST</a>
                            <a class="submenuTitle" href="#">CHRISTIAN LOUBOUTIN</a>
                            <a class="submenuTitle" href="#">BALENCIAGA</a>
                            <a class="submenuTitle" href="#">CHANEL</a>
                    </div>
                </div>                
                <div class="submenu_Container">
                    <div class="submenu_menuContainer">
                        <p class="clotheCategory">LEATHER GOODS </p>
                            <a class="submenuTitle" href="#">WALLETS</a>
                            <a class="submenuTitle" href="#">GLOVES</a>
                            <a class="submenuTitle" href="#">BELTS</a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="submenu_menuContainer">
                        <p class="clotheCategory">BAGS</p>
                            <a class="submenuTitle" href="#">LOUIS VUITTON</a>
                            <a class="submenuTitle" href="#">PRADA</a>
                            <a class="submenuTitle" href="#">HERMÉS</a>
                            <a class="submenuTitle" href="#">MARC JACOBS</a>
                            <a class="submenuTitle" href="#">OTHERS</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class='mySlider'>
   <div class='sangar-content'>
                <img src='http://hamderser.dk/blog/images/clairvoyant/clairvoyant-nature-nature6.jpg' />
            </div>
   <div class='sangar-content'>
                <img src='http://hamderser.dk/blog/images/clairvoyant/clairvoyant-nature-nature6.jpg' />
            </div>    
   <div class='sangar-content'>
                <img src='http://hamderser.dk/blog/images/clairvoyant/clairvoyant-nature-nature6.jpg' />
            </div>
   <div class='sangar-content'>
                <img src='http://hamderser.dk/blog/images/clairvoyant/clairvoyant-nature-nature6.jpg' />
            </div>
   <div class='sangar-content'>
                <img src='http://hamderser.dk/blog/images/clairvoyant/clairvoyant-nature-nature6.jpg' />
            </div>    

      </div>
        <div id="sections">
            <div id="section_1_master_container">
                <div id="section_1_container">
                    <div class="title_bar_container">
                        <p class="section_news_title">LATEST NEWS</p>
                        <a class="view_older_news" href="#">OLDER NEWS</a>
                    </div>
                    <div id="news_container">
                        <div class="item_container">
                            <div class="item_options_container">
                                <a class="options_icon"></a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="author_container">
                                <a class="author_image" ></a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="news_title">
                                <p class="title_text">Welcome</p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="news_content">
                                <p class="content_text">
                                Hello, and welcome. We are proud to welcome you to this site. We hope you like it. This is my first company whatsoever, so i ope you like it. We have features like: Auctioning, selling (only applies for brand new items), trading and requesting. We hope you like these features, i assure you: We will keep updating with more features and important Do you need any help? Did you find a bug? Head over to the support, and let us know!</p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="tags_readmore_container">
                                <div class="tags_container">
                                    <a class="tag">Welcome</a>
                                    <a class="tag">Hello</a>
                                    <a class="tag">Release</a>
                                </div>
                                <div class="readmore_container" href="#">
                                    <a class="readmore_text">Read more<a class="readmore_icon"></a></a>                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="published_date_container">
                                <p class="published_date">Published - 1/1/2016</p>   
                            </div>
                        </div>
                                                
                        <div class="item_container">
                            <div class="item_options_container">
                                <a class="options_icon"></a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="author_container">
                                <a class="author_image" ></a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="news_title">
                                <p class="title_text">Welcome</p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="news_content">
                                <p class="content_text">
                                Hello, and welcome. We are proud to welcome you to this site. We hope you like it. This is my first company whatsoever, so i ope you like it. We have features like: Auctioning, selling (only applies for brand new items), trading and requesting. We hope you like these features, i assure you: We will keep updating with more features and important Do you need any help? Did you find a bug? Head over to the support, and let us know!</p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="tags_readmore_container">
                                <div class="tags_container">
                                    <a class="tag">Welcome</a>
                                    <a class="tag">Hello</a>
                                    <a class="tag">Release</a>
                                </div>
                                <div class="readmore_container" href="#">
                                    <a class="readmore_text">Read more<a class="readmore_icon"></a></a>                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="published_date_container">
                                <p class="published_date">Published - 1/1/2016</p>   
                            </div>
                        </div>
                                                
                        <div class="item_container">
                            <div class="item_options_container">
                                <a class="options_icon"></a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="author_container">
                                <a class="author_image" ></a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="news_title">
                                <p class="title_text">Welcome</p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="news_content">
                                <p class="content_text">
                                Hello, and welcome. We are proud to welcome you to this site. We hope you like it. This is my first company whatsoever, so i ope you like it. We have features like: Auctioning, selling (only applies for brand new items), trading and requesting. We hope you like these features, i assure you: We will keep updating with more features and important Do you need any help? Did you find a bug? Head over to the support, and let us know!</p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="tags_readmore_container">
                                <div class="tags_container">
                                    <a class="tag">Welcome</a>
                                    <a class="tag">Hello</a>
                                    <a class="tag">Release</a>
                                </div>
                                <div class="readmore_container" href="#">
                                    <a class="readmore_text">Read more<a class="readmore_icon"></a></a>                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="published_date_container">
                                <p class="published_date">Published - 1/1/2016</p>   
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        
                                                
                        <div class="item_container">
                            <div class="item_options_container">
                                <a class="options_icon"></a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="author_container">
                                <a class="author_image" ></a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="news_title">
                                <p class="title_text">Welcome</p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="news_content">
                                <p class="content_text">
                                Hello, and welcome. We are proud to welcome you to this site. We hope you like it. This is my first company whatsoever, so i ope you like it. We have features like: Auctioning, selling (only applies for brand new items), trading and requesting. We hope you like these features, i assure you: We will keep updating with more features and important Do you need any help? Did you find a bug? Head over to the support, and let us know!</p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="tags_readmore_container">
                                <div class="tags_container">
                                    <a class="tag">Welcome</a>
                                    <a class="tag">Hello</a>
                                    <a class="tag">Release</a>
                                </div>
                                <div class="readmore_container" href="#">
                                    <a class="readmore_text">Read more<a class="readmore_icon"></a></a>                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="published_date_container">
                                <p class="published_date">Published - 1/1/2016</p>   
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        
                        
                    </div>
                </div>
                <a class="arrow-down"></a>
            </div>
            <div id="section_2_container">
                <div id="section_2_title_container">
                    <p class="social_title">LATEST MEDIA</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="footer">
                    
            </div>
        </div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS 1:

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
   /* background-color: #7F8C8D; */
}
/* MENU */
#navBar {
    background-color: #464646;
    height: 65px;
    width: 100%; 
    display: -webkit-box;
}
#logo {
    width: 15%;
    margin-left: 2.5%;
    margin-right: 2.5%;
    height: 65px;
}
#menu {
    height: 65px;
    width: auto;
}
#menuTitle_Container{
    width: auto;
    display: -webkit-inline-box;
}
.menuTitle{
    font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 17px;
    padding-right: 10px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    color: #fff;
    vertical-align: text-top;
    line-height: 65px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: -webkit-block;
    display: block;
    transition: color 0.4s ease;
    transition: background-color 0.4s ease;
}
.menuTitle:nth-child(+n+2):hover, .menuTitle.active {
    background-color: #fff;
    transition: background-color 0.4s ease, color 0.4s ease;
    color: #353535;
}

/* DROPDOWN MENU  ON HOVER */

#dropdownMenu {
    width: 750px;
    height: 250px;
    background-color: #fff;
    margin-left: 20%;
    display: none;
    opacity: 0;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1000;
}
#mensmenu {
    height: 100;   
}
.submenu_Container {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: none;
}
.submenu_menuContainer {
    width: 50%;
    height: 190px;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-top: 30px;
    margin-left: 5%;
}
.submenu_menuContainer:nth-child(1) {
    border-right: 1px solid #B3B3B3;
}


.clotheCategory {
    font-family: 'open sans', sans-serif;
    font-size: 15px;
    color: #353535;
    font-weight: 600;
    margin-top: 10px;
    text-align: center;
}
.submenuTitle {
    font-family: 'open sans', sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: 400;
    color: #353535;
    margin-top: 10px;
    display: table;
}
```

CSS 2:

```css
#sections {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
}

#section_1_master_container {
    height: 39%;
    width: 90%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

/* NEWS */

#section_1_container {
    height: 39%;
    width: 100%;
}
.title_bar_container {
    text-align: right;
}

.section_news_title {
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    font-size: 25px;
    font-weight: 500;
    color: #000;
    text-align: center;
    height: 5%;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    margin-top: 1%;
    padding-bottom: 6px;  
}
.view_older_news{
    font-family: 'Roboto Condensed', sans-serif;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: 600;
    color: #656565;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    transition: color 0.4s ease;
}
.view_older_news:hover {
    color: #3498DB;
    transition: color 0.4s ease;
}

#news_container {
    height: 34%;
    width: 100%;
}

.item_container {
    height: 285px;
    width: 350px;
    background-color: #FFF;
    display: inline-table;
    margin-left: 35px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-right: 35px;
    border: 1px solid #D6D5D5;
}
.item_options_container {
    height: 20px;
    width: 20px;
    margin-right: 5px;
    float: right;
}
.options_icon{
    background-image: url(sprites/Ellipsis_64.png);
    background-size: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    width: 20px;
    position: absolute;
    opacity: 0.8;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: opacity 0.4s ease;
}
.options_icon:hover {
    opacity: 1;
    transition: opacity 0.4s ease;
}
.author_container {
    height:35px;
    width: auto;
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    display: -webkit-box;
    position: absolute;
}
.author_image {
    background-image: url(images/11205160_460606354116178_4059863531143056611_n.jpg);
    background-size: 35px;
    height: 35px;
    width: 35px;
    border-radius: 17.5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 17.5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 175px;
    opacity: 0.6;
    transition: opacity 0.4s ease;
    cursor:pointer;
    position: absolute;
}
.author_image:hover {
    opacity: 1;
    transition: opacity 0.4s ease;
}
.news_title {
    width: 200px;
    height: auto;
    line-height: 55px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
.title_text {
    font-family: 'PT Sans', sans-serif;
    font-size: 19px;
    font-weight: 700;
    color: #000;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0;
}
.news_content {
    height: 160px;
    width: 290px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-top: 10px;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
.content_text{
    font-family: 'PT Sans', sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #4C4C4C;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 0;
    height: 160px;
    width: 290px;
}
.tags_readmore_container {
    width: 100%;
    height: 35px;
    display: -webkit-inline-box;
}
.tags_container {
    width: 160px;
    height: 35px;
    display: block;
    margin-left: 31px;
    margin-top: 2px;
}
.tag {
    height: 12x;
    width: auto;
    padding-left: 4px;
    padding-right: 4px;
    background-color: #616161;
    line-height: 12px;
    
    font-family: 'PT Sans', sans-serif;
    font-size: 10px;
    color: #EFEFEF;
    
}
.readmore_container {
    width: auto;
    height: 20px;
    margin-top: 4px;
    margin-left: 40px;
    text-decoration: none;
    opacity: 0.8;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: opacity 0.4s ease;
}
.readmore_container:hover{
    opacity: 1;
    transition: opacity 0.4s ease;
}
.readmore_text {
    line-height: 20px;
    font-family: 'PT Sans', sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
    color: #303030;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.readmore_icon{
    background-image: url(sprites/Right_straight_arrow_64.png);
    background-size: 12px;
    height: 12px;
    width: 12px;
    position: absolute;
    margin-left: 5px;
    vertical-align: bottom;
    margin-top: 5px;
}   
.published_date_container {
    height: 12px;
    width: 100px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.published_date {
    font-family: 'PT Sans' sans-serif;
    font-size: 10px; 
    color: #C3C3C3;
    text-align: center;
}

/* SOCIAL */

#section_2_container{
    width: 100%;
    height: 67%;
    margin-top: 30px;
}
#section_2_title_container {
    width: 140px;
    height: 100%;
    margin-left: 5%;
    border-right: 1px solid #BDC3C7;
}
.social_title {
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    font-size: 25px;
    font-weight: 500;
    color: #000;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 40px;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    text-align: -webkit-right;
    margin-right: 20px;
    display: inline-block;
}
/* FOOTER */
#footer {
    height: 30%;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #4C4C4C;
    margin-top:30px;
}
```

Comment: Are you familiar with the concept of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Responsive_web_design? You are using a bunch of fixed sized elements instead of using relative units like ems and percentages.

Comment: I know the best way is to use percentage and ems, but items as the news items, is just better with px's i guess. The slider is not possible to change to percentage, not right now. The height and width is done in jquery (slider found online), and i haven't yet found out where to define it as percentage or ems. I will look into this though. I will lookup your wiki page, thanks for the link. Stupid of me not to have looked into it before.

Comment: Responsive web design is tough, but there is a lot of info out there on it. The main goal is to get the site functional against a slew of resolutions. Also "Mobile First" is a big thing right now as well. Good luck.

Comment: @JoshNaro So is it possible to make it zoom out to be the same on other computers? some meta tag? Because when i zoom out, it works looks good.

Comment: I think you would probably need to go with re-flowing content (e.g. four news stories wide on some screens and 3 on others), relative-based dimensions (e.g. percentages), media queries in your CSS (to change the dimensions of your nature pic depending on screen size), or some combination of those. There's no magic/easy fix for what you are trying to do.

Comment: @JoshNaro: the main problem, at first, would be the slider, since the slider is the one filling up the space. The slider used is the Tonjoo Sangar jQuery slider. I'm looking through the code now, but i can't seem to spot where they declare if its px or percentage used, i'm not really that well known in jQuery. EDIT: Git link: https://github.com/tonjoo/jQuery-Sangar-Slider

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to SO. Your call to the jquery plugin contains the slider's height and width as fixed pixel sizes. Altering to a percentage or using `200em` style sizing  will allow the browser to scale automatically. This is after all described as **responsive** although the demos aren't perfect (height resizes but does not subtract the menu height from it, so it goes off the screen a little but not passively, tested on 1200x800 resolution tablet).

Your height is set here:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
        jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
            $('.mySlider').sangarSlider({
                timer : true, // true or false to have the timer
                width : 850, // slideshow width
                height : 500, // slideshow height
                fullWidth : true, // slider will scale to the container size
                fullHeight : false, // slideshow height will resize to browser height
                minHeight : 400, // slideshow min height
                maxHeight : 500, // slideshow max height, set to '0' (zero) to make it unlimited   
                continousSliding : false, // only works for horizontal-slide and vertical-slide      
                jsOnly : false,                 
                directionalNav : 'autohide',
                themeClass : 'default'
            });
        })
    </script>
```

Note the `width:800` (but overwritten presumably by `fullWidth: true` -but you have `height:500` without using `fullHeight` lines along with the `minHeight:400`.

The github file describes the slider as **responsive** - before doing anything else [check all the parameters for the plug-in](https://github.com/tonjoo/jQuery-Sangar-Slider/blob/master/readme.md)  and add `scaleImage: true` when calling it - however the [responsive.css](https://github.com/tonjoo/jQuery-Sangar-Slider/blob/master/dist/css/responsive.css) is blank.

Looking at the `.js` however suggest passing a percentage height into your plug-in call (code at the top of this reply) should work, eg `height:60%`

Edit: this answer refers to css in the [dist] (https://github.com/tonjoo/jQuery-Sangar-Slider/tree/master/dist/css) folder which uses the `image` tag and `img` class, ie `image.img` in css and does not appear fixed in pixels.

The responsive [carousel demo](http://tonjoo.com/demo/jQuery-Sangar-Slider/demo/sample-carousel.html) works.

Comment: Thank you, I will try this. Give me a few minutes and I will come back with an answer if it worked or not. I did know that i made the height there and so, but the thing with percentage was new. Thanks again.

Comment: The thing with percentage didn't work out. In one of the .js files I found, where it seems like they declare which unit to use. Still can't trigger why it doesn't work. Hmm.

Comment: UPDATE: if you head to assets > js > SangarSlider > sangarSizeAndScale.js , then there is a lot with px's, do you think that can be it? I will just test it out and see if it works.

Comment: @Marcus Pilegaard I was working from the css in the `dist` folder, answer updated to identify the exact files and link to the responsive carousel demo that works. You may want to edit your facebook ID out of the original code and link to the image instead

Comment: I see, my site is using the assets files though hmm. Nothing seems to work... Weird. The Facebook stuff has nothing to do with this? it's not connected in anyway, right now.

Comment: Is it possible to create a chat somewhere here, so we can chat about this? Seems like I do not have the required reputation to do so, and comments is getting filled up.

Comment: chat needs a greater reputatin still, but you can edit your previous comments to add a line to each. 
Creating a [jsfiddlet](http://jsfiddle.net) lets you paste in code and test it multiple times as well as letting others check it. You could either put yout code in a jsfiddle - or copy the working demo code I posted the link to. I've just looked at the `.js` again and it could be the demo is working because of a custom responsive css file. 
Runing you code with a direct link to the demo css should tell you if that is the issue.

Comment: I will try to add a jsfiddle, if possible. There is a lot of code linked to the slider, so i have no idea how to link all of it in a jsfiddle.